# how to check if auth.uid matches a field in the database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'd like to write a role which checks if auth.uid matches a certain field.

I tested the following rules with the simulator and get a permission denied.
The user_id in the database is a string with the same uid I used in the simulator.

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userName": {
        "avatar": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "data.child('users').child($userName).child('user_id').val() === auth.uid",
        },
        "user_id": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": false,
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with both `firebase-realtime-database` and `google-cloud-firestore`. The two databases are completely separate, and you'll seldom need to tag a question with both of them. I removed the Firestore tag, since your question includes security rules for the Realtime Database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you update your question to include a snippet of the relevant JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). It would also be helpful to see the operation that fails, like in a screenshot of the simulator.